# The meaning of "Never give a sucker an even break."

Tags: sentence-meaning

resource: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Hustle

What does the sentence mean?

Don't give a loser a fair treatment?

Don't let a sucker have a rest? (So he/she continues sucking you)

Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "sucker" is someone who can be easily deceived. And "an even break" is a fair chance of winning.

So it means (If you want to get the most money from the sucker) don't give him a fair chance.

It is advice that one "hustler" might give to another. A hustler is a person who steals money by tricking people.

The expression (and several of the other quotes from "Hustlers") 
is a quote from W C Fields, and was used as a title of one of his later films.

Comment: The line is from a film with W.C. Fields.

Comment: Actually the line, delivered and written by Fields, is used in several of his films, perhaps most famously in "You Can't Cheat an Honest Man." Whipsnade says that his grandfather's dying advice, given "just before they sprung the trap," was  "Never give a sucker an even break; you can't cheat an honest man, and never smarten up a chump."